# How do the people in a one-party dictatorship take out their frustration at their government?

Tags: democracy

If there are some political parties in a country, the nation can take out their frustration at their government by changing the political party at the polls.

However it can't do it in a one-party dictatorship. How do the people in a one-party dictatorship take out their frustration at their government?

Comment: Revolt? Not sure exactly what you are getting at here. Taking out your frustration is really a psychological question not a political question.

Comment: It's not my frustration. I just want to know them.

Comment: The question should be : how can people express themselves in a dictatorship ??

Comment: If you are frustrated with the party, you are free to take out your frustrating by hacking away at rocks in one of many of the party's mandatory dissident labor camps. The party provides this service for your own good.

Comment: If I have frustrations at our government, I just will vote the other political party in my country.

Comment: Normally, dictatorship have little patience with protesters. If you speak too loud, you will end up in jail of worse. In a democracy we can vote and we can protest but neither are tolerated in a dictatorship.

Comment: Yes, it seems so.

Comment: I don't know who deleted my comments

Comment: Then how can people collect my thoughts after I die? Well, there will be no equals to _the Republic_.

Comment: Do u mean frustration with ideology or with some actions/personalities? These are totally different things.

Comment: @Anixx as seen in China http://www.technologyreview.com/news/519066/academics-launch-fake-social-network-to-get-an-inside-look-at-chinese-censorship/

Comment: @user45891 it seems the link does not provide insight into political views of the poeple in question and also is not related to the elections.

Comment: "By carefully choosing the content of posts to create a randomized trial, King’s group showed that censors don’t target complaints about the government. Instead, they’re much more concerned about talk of collective action." "Ng says that adds numerical weight to a common perception amongst China experts that the country’s government finds it useful to allow people to vent frustrations online. “Allowing people to post about corrupt officials is a tool government can use,” as in the Chinese people can complain about their local fly but not about the general system @Anixx

Comment: @user45891 so can you please clarify about what the question is? Where the people in Chine can report the corruption cases besides on the internet or what?

Comment: Neither. They can't report it but the Chinese Government (a one-party dictatorship) allows(==doesn't block) it's citizens to vent frustration about individual persons but does not allow dissent about the actual political system or calls for action. They allow to blow off some steam but try to block that which threatens the system

Comment: I assume like everyone else does...by posting silly political rants on Facebook.

Answer (score 8):

The theory goes that people turn their attention to other things. Entertainment, Patriotism, Family Life, Ambition through Approved Channels. Basically the same habits the West had prior to the 19th century.

We have to remember that until recently<sup>1</sup>, human civilization made its way without direct representation of the majority of its population. Democracy has a wide range of advantages but these aren't necessarily intuitive to people who've never had it and are preoccupied with day-to-day concerns<sup>2</sup>.

The minority that couldn't ignore the system (and had a choice in the matter) could either choose to emigrate or to join the ruling party. The second option isn't as unusual as it may seem. After all, that's where the moderates in an oligarchy come from.

It's when the second or third generation of otherwise acclimatised middle-class bureaucrats flee the country that you know it's on the way out.

<sub>1. Or not at all, depending on your cynicism.</sub>
<sub>2. Same reason why bipartisan corrosion of democracy is ignored here.</sub>

Comment: Theory goes - you may want to add a cite to who postulates that theory

Answer (score 4):

This answer is about methods of *taking out* your frustration, as opposed to merely dealing with it or avoiding it.

Secret societies were invented for that exact purpose: You get together, anonymously, perhaps you even put on masks, and then you start bitching. Occasionally, action originates. This is how Freemasonry got its traction in the 19th century.

Another option was covert ridicule: Here is a lyric from a medieval German folk song:

```
Oh hang high
the loral wreath
him our prince
we shall revere
```

If you skip every second line the lyrics read

```
Oh hang high
him our prince
```

This couldn't have fooled anybody for long, but censors would most likely be overworked and understaffed and focused making examples of the most overt ridicule.

In a similar vein, a 19th century Prussian newspaper wrote a story about a shopkeeper who so revered Bismarck he printed his quotes on his toilet paper.

Apparently metaphor was not illegal.

There was, of course, also the tried and tested method of verbally or physically abusing your wife, dog, children and possibly subordinates; if these were not available, chopping wood has likewise stood the test of time.

Similarly, institutionalized animal cruelty was also considered quite liberating to oppressed people; the public spectacle of cat burning or blood sports like cock fighting seem to regularly disappear along with systematic human cruelty.

Black magic and other types of private symbolic malevolence also appear to enjoy more popularity in repressive settings.

Covert sabotage and willful ineffectiveness are among the safest routes to derive satisfaction by actually getting some form of revenge.

When oppression is based on moral grounds, secretly gathering in large groups and deliberately doing lots of forbidden acts in a short amount of time can release considerable pressure. Iranian dance parties come to mind, where kids gather in cellars, do ecstasy, listen to techno music with orgastic scream samples, knock back poorly mixed but graciously available gin and tonics, and perhaps shed the head cloth and other involuntary textiles.

The most rare, extreme and unpredictable possibility was, of course, to found or join an insurgency.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at Saudi-Arabia it looks like formulating your political views in a religious language is a popular choice in that part of the world.

Comment: Huh. You're right. I entirely forgot the religious side-channel for political expression. I guess I was wrapped up thinking about secular dictatorships. +1

Comment: Also in South American dictatorship it was often channelled in religion, for example liberation theology.

Comment: @SVilcans Do you have some examples? I always enjoy subversive ingenuity.

Comment: @SVilcans For example, how would a Saudi subversive religiously legitimize his lust for booze and loose women? I know you can get a ten minute marriage license in Iranian brothels.

Answer (score 1):

When people's desires are thwarted, their oppressed energy will find outlets in twisted forms, such as feverish pursuits of American dollar which is fiat with no intrinsic value. Democracy has intrinsic values because participation itself is a great source of happiness.

On the other hand, democracy is both an idea and a habit. We can no more expect a country to be democratic overnight than we can a people to be fluent in a foreign language in a matter of weeks. We need to create more Hong Kongs, more Taiwans and more South Koreas as forward operation bases of civilization, to spread modern ideas and to cultivate good habits.

Comment: Now President Xi has just warned against "immoral" art. That is exactly the kind of thing witarded people say.

Comment: Without intending to one-up you, and with plenty of sympathy for alternative currency enthusiasm, I you are giving unrelated opinions without answering the question.